# Extract data from JSON in URL (real-time)

Tags: javascript, html, json, weebly

I am a green hand in building websites. The Hong Kong government recently released real-time open data on vacant parking spaces. I would like to display vacant spaces in a parking lot on my Weebly website. Could anyone help me with this by using the embed code? Thanks a lot!

For example, the vacancy of the car park is "12" now, I want to display "12" on my Weebly page.

Open data website provided by the government: https://sps-opendata.pilotsmartke.gov.hk/rest/getCarparkVacancy?carparkId=10

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rJhY.jpg)

This is my try, but it shows all data, how can I achieve the data for "vacancy" only.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Fetch a file to change this text.</p>

<script>
let file = "https://sps-opendata.pilotsmartke.gov.hk/rest/getCarparkVacancy?carparkId=10"
fetch (file)
.then(x => x.text())
.then(y => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`
// function that pulls the data from the api and displays it on the html page
function search() {

const url = `https://sps-opendata.pilotsmartke.gov.hk/rest/getCarparkVacancy?carparkId=10`

fetch(url)
.then (response => response.json())
.then (data => {

vacancy = data.results.privateCar.vacancy

document.getElementById("htmlIdOfWhereIWantThisToDisplay").textContent = vacancy

})

}
// call the function
search()`

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @moken my answer was fine, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully written it myself. Thank you for all the guidance, and I will put my code here for others' reference.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Fetch a file to change this text.</p>

<script>
let file = "https://sps-opendata.pilotsmartke.gov.hk/rest/getCarparkVacancy?carparkId=10"
fetch (file)
.then(x => x.json())
.then(y => document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = y.results.privateCar.vacancy);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```